# Lost wifi on Ubuntu with Intel AC 8265 after updating firmware

Tags: networking, wireless

I had Ubuntu 18.04.4 installed on my Lenovo ThinkStation p330 and I was able to connect to wifi right after it was installed. A few days ago when I was using Windows, I was asked by Lenovo to update BIOS firmware and drivers. I did that under Windows. Now when I boot Ubuntu, there is no wifi (although everything works fine under Windows). I don't know if the problem was reinstalling the firmware, but I cannot see any other reason for losing wifi under Ubuntu.

The wifi controller is Intel AC 8265.

Please kindly assist.

As requested providing the feedback:

`dmesg | grep iwl` produced:

```
[    2.837836] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.844195] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.9f0a2d68.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.862215] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
[    3.907541] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[    4.156253] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[    4.156303] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[    4.156341] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0EC5873A | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    4.156345] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x28E18410 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    4.156350] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x15C08825 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    4.156354] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000A10B | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    4.156391] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xDABF41B8 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    4.156429] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xBF5928F6 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    4.156467] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x4478BE0B | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    4.156472] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x41CA4063 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    4.156476] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000010 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    4.156517] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0BADCAFE | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    4.156558] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0BADCAFE | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    4.156597] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0BADCAFE | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    4.156728] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x3, CPU2 Status: 0x28a7
[    4.156729] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[    4.156763] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    4.169215] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

also `lshw -C network` produced:

```
*-network
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 78
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:135 memory:b1100000-b1101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno1
       version: 10
       serial: 98:fa:9b:af:53:e1
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.5-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:126 memory:b1300000-b131ffff
```

Comment: This is only a hunch, but you may be able to fix this by going into software sources>additional drivers and allowing the system to find any additional drivers, you might also need to enable proprietary sources on the initial page of software sources.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep iwl` Is this a possible issue? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: As you requested, I executed the code and provided feedback.