# Wi-Fi Adapter Not Found

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi, adapter

I am really new to Linux, I can connect to the internet trough Ethernet cables but it doesn't show any Wi-Fi options. This computer used to have Windows 10 but I erased it, Secure and Fast Boot are deactivated. I have an Asus

Can someone help me please?

```
    sudo lshw -C network 

  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 78
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fea00000-fea01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: 18:31:bf:41:f2:96
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-48-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.228 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:28 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fe904000-fe904fff memory:fe900000-fe903fff
```

Aditional Info :

```
    lspci -knn | grep -i Net -A3
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:0110]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

dmesg | grep iwl
[   11.204608] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   11.289883] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -110
[   13.329796] Modules linked in: edac_mce_amd amdgpu kvm_amd ccp uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btusb kvm videobuf2_common iommu_v2 btrtl btbcm videodev crct10dif_pclmul btintel gpu_sched ghash_clmulni_intel ttm bluetooth snd_hda_codec_generic mc iwlwifi drm_kms_helper snd_hda_codec_hdmi ledtrig_audio aesni_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg ecdh_generic ecc cec rc_core joydev i2c_algo_bit asus_nb_wmi snd_hda_codec fb_sys_fops crypto_simd hid_multitouch syscopyarea asus_wmi cfg80211 sysfillrect cryptd snd_hda_core input_leds serio_raw sysimgblt glue_helper snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event sparse_keymap snd_rawmidi snd_seq efi_pstore k10temp fam15h_power snd_seq_device wmi_bmof snd_timer snd asus_wireless 8250_dw soundcore mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic crc32_pclmul sdhci_pci cqhci sdhci ahci i2c_piix4 libahci xhci_pci r8169 xhci_pci_renesas realtek wmi video i2c_hid hid

uname -a
Linux Laptop-Anton 5.8.0-48-generic #54~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Mar 20 13:40:25 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$  dpkg -l | grep linux-modules
ii  linux-modules-5.4.0-70-generic             5.4.0-70.78                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.8.0-43-generic             5.8.0-43.49~20.04.1                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.8.0-48-generic             5.8.0-48.54~20.04.1                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-70-generic       5.4.0-70.78                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ic  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-43-generic       5.8.0-43.49~20.04.1                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ic  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-48-generic       5.8.0-48.54~20.04.1                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

`lsmod | grep iwl` - No output

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
modprobe: FATAL: Module mac80211 not found.
modprobe: FATAL: Error running remove command for iwlwifi


sudo modprobe iwlwifi
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:838 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='iwlwifi'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Unknown symbol in module,or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

Comment: please show command `rfkill list all`

Comment: `rfkill list all                                                                                                                             0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no`

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

1. If you have a Lenovo, [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=285630) may help you (newer versions may be available)

   ```
   $ sudo apt install git dkms build-essential
   $ git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/ideapad-laptop.git
   $ sudo dkms add ./ideapad-laptop
   $ sudo dkms install ideapad-laptop/1.0
   ```
2. What you posted shows the driver (as per [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236773/lost-wifi-on-ubuntu-with-intel-ac-8265-after-updating-firmware), it should be `iwlwifi`) is not used for your WiFi.
   You may then try [disabling Windows Fast Start feature](https://askubuntu.com/a/1279275/226614) and rebooting.
3. You can also try

   ```
   $ sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
   $ sudo modprobe iwlwifi
   ```
4. Perhaps you are missing some modules. Try

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install linux-base linux-modules-<kernel version>-generic linux-modules-extra-<kernel version>-generic
   ```

Additional info would help:

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl
$ lspci -knn | grep -i Net -A3
$ rfkill list all
$ lsmod | grep iwl

$ uname -a
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-modules
```

**Related**:

1. [Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Intel 7260 Wireless - won't connect to Wifi network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230922/ubuntu-20-04-lts-intel-7260-wireless-wont-connect-to-wifi-network)
2. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html
3. [Lost wifi on Ubuntu with Intel AC 8265 after updating firmware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236773/lost-wifi-on-ubuntu-with-intel-ac-8265-after-updating-firmware)
4. https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/component/8086:24fd
5. https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=269043

Comment: `$ sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi`
`modprobe: FATAL: Module mac80211 not found.
modprobe: FATAL: Error running remove command for iwlwifi`
 
Is this supposed to happen?

`$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:838 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='iwlwifi'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)`

Comment: I have put the aditional info in the original post

Comment: @ant-onio - Please do the following (I won't be able to help further without this knowledge):
1) Post the results in the question instead of in coments.
2) Post in the question what happened when you tried disabling fast boot, and rebooted.
3) See edited answer and follow it.

Comment: I've done the first thing you asked, nothing happened when i disabled fast boot, this showed up when i placed the 4 (about the missing modules) `bash: kernel: No such file or directory
`

Comment: @sancho-s-reinstatemonicacellio thanks for all the help, magically today everything worked out, I dont know how.

Comment: @ant-onio - Well... who knows then? Good luck

Comment: Reinstalling `linux-modules-extra-<kernel version>-generic` did the trick for me, thanks for the super-detailed answer with so many fallback plans!